# Trees in context

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, trees

Excuse me for my english, is not my language. I have a document in LaTeX, the relevant code is

```
\documentclass[a4 paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=60pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.¿$\leqslant 32$? [.¿$\leqslant 16$? [.¿$\leqslant 8$?  [.¿$\leqslant 4$? [.¿$\leqslant 2$?  [.¿$\leqslant 1$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 3$? ] ] [.¿$\leqslant 6$? [.¿$\leqslant 5$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 7$? ]   ] ]
[. ¿$\leqslant 12$? [.¿$\leqslant 10$? [.¿$\leqslant 9$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 11$? ]   ] [.¿$\leqslant 14$?  [.¿$\leqslant 13$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 15$? ]  ] ]   ] [.¿$\leqslant 24$? [.¿$\leqslant 20$? [.¿$\leqslant 18$?  [.¿$\leqslant 17$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 19$? ] ] [.¿$\leqslant 22$? [.¿$\leqslant 21$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 23$? ]  ]    ] [.¿$\leqslant 28$?  [.¿$\leqslant 26$?   [.¿$\leqslant 25$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 27$? ] ] [.¿$\leqslant 30$? [.¿$\leqslant 29$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 31$? ]]  ] ] ]
%
%
%
[.¿$\leqslant 48$? [.¿$\leqslant 40$?  [.¿$\leqslant 36$? [.¿$\leqslant 34$?  [.¿$\leqslant 33$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 35$? ] ] [.¿$\leqslant 38$? [.¿$\leqslant 37$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 39$? ]   ] ]
[. ¿$\leqslant 44$? [.¿$\leqslant 42$? [.¿$\leqslant 41$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 43$? ]   ] [.¿$\leqslant 46$?  [.¿$\leqslant 45$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 47$? ]  ] ]   ] [.¿$\leqslant 56$? [.¿$\leqslant 52$? [.¿$\leqslant 50$?  [.¿$\leqslant 49$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 51$? ] ] [.¿$\leqslant 54$? [.¿$\leqslant 53$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 55$? ]  ]    ] [.¿$\leqslant 60$?  [.¿$\leqslant 58$?   [.¿$\leqslant 57$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 59$? ] ] [.¿$\leqslant 62$? [.¿$\leqslant 61$? ] [.¿$\leqslant 63$? ]]  ] ] ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to translate it to ConTeXt, so I've put `\usemodule[tikz]` before `\starttext`, and I could obtain several TikZ pictures in my new ConTexT document. But I could not obtain this tree, cause I have not idea about how make work the analog of `\usepackage{tikz-qtree}` in ConTeXt.
I'd appreciate all help, either about put tikz-qtree at work or about how to obtain the same tree without a sintactical nightmare.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried loading `tikz-qtree` as a module or inputting `tikz-qtree.tex` etc.?

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far for the ConTeXt translation.

Comment: You can edit your question using the grey link at the bottom left of it `edit`.

Comment: It looks as if you could *probably* input the `.tex` files for `tikz-qtree` rather than using the LaTeX packages. Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: Thank you. The ConTeX code is

\usemodule[tikz]  
\usemodule[tikz-qtree]

\starttext

\placefigure[left][arbol]{}{\hbox{\starttikzpicture[scale=0.8]

(the same code as above, too long to put it here, beginning with "\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=60pt}" and ending with "[.¿$\leqslant 63$? ]]  ] ] ]]").

\stoptikzpicture}}

\stoptext

Comment: I don't know how to input the .tex files of tikz-qtree in a ConTeXt  document. But I think I can search the way to do that in some document or here.

Comment: To input a `.tex` file, `\input <filename>.tex`.

Comment: @cfr: The error is due to catcodes. If you load the files with a catcode table where `@` is a letter, the module works. See my answer.

Comment: @Aditya I did try to do that but obviously failed to attempt it correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the code in `qtree-tikz` is TeX code, which one exception: `pgfsubpic.sty` uses `\begin{...} .. \end{...}`, which is easy to circumvent. Here is an example from the `qtree-tikz` manual:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\unprotect
\input pgfsubpic
\input pgftree
\input tikz-qtree
\protect

% Poor man's \begin{...} ... \end{...}
\define[1]\begin{\bgroup\csname#1\endcsname \let\end\latexend}
\define[1]\latexend{\csname end#1\endcsname\egroup}

\starttext
\starttikzpicture
\Tree [.S [.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
      [.VP [.V sat ]
           [.PP [.P on ]
                [.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]